# Why does Xubuntu asks for my password twice when it wakes up from the blank screen?

Tags: xubuntu, lock-screen, screensaver

Every time Xubuntu wakes up from the blank screen it asks for my password and then, after I enter it, it asks for it again. This doesn't happen if I lock the screen manually. How can this be fixed?